# Winform: Get the form location before showing (StartupPosition is CenterScreen)

Tags: c#, winforms, position

Is there anyway to do this? In my understanding it should be possible, but if I try `myForm.Location` before showing the form I get `(0, 0)`.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need this information for?

Comment: Despite this form is showing as a modal dialog (`ShowDialog`), before showing it I need to show other form which will be positioned according this forms position.

Comment: I have a followup question for you guys..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613124/is-there-a-way-to-get-windows-to-ignore-the-manual-windowstartuplocation-im-usi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to know the location of the form is to decide where you want and put it there.

```
   Form formDemo = new DemoForm();
   formDemo.Location = new Point(20, 30);
   formDemo.Show(); //or formDemo.ShowDialog();
```

After @Diego clarified his question I believe this will do what is needed:

```
    int ScreenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
    int ScreenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
    int formTop = (ScreenHeight/2) - (formDemo.Height / 2);
    int formLeft = (ScreenWidth/2) - (formDemo.Width / 2);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think there is a misunderstandin. The form has CenterScreen as StartupPosition, and that how it needs to be. What I need is to know what location would it mean for that form to start centered in the screen.

Comment: I think it is, I'll accept the answer, but I'll be testing it tomorrow. Hope it works!

Comment: It is not correct, the form's Height and Width properties change to accommodate the video adapter's DPI setting.  You *have* to wait until the Load event fires.  Only then do you know the real size (and location) of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think technically you don't HAVE a position before it is drawn. I personally don't know of a way to convert the "System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition" enumerable to a Point.

However for what you want, it should be quite simple. I would show the first form, then pass it's bounds to the second form where you can set it's start up logic to use those for it's positioning. like so.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);
    }

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowForm2(this.Bounds);
    }  

    public void ShowForm2(Rectangle ParentBounds)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();

        int x = ParentBounds.Right+2;
        int y = ParentBounds.Y + (ParentBounds.Height/2) - (f.Height/2);

        Point childStartPosition = new Point(x,y);

        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        f.Location = childStartPosition;
        f.Show();
    }
```